# Games based on sheaves (or sheaf gluing?)

Tags: math-history, sheaf-theory, combinatorial-game-theory, sheaf-cohomology

my question is quite simple (and I hope it is NOT stupid).

It is well-known that many successful games have clear mathematical underpinnings (see for example http://web.mit.edu/sp.268/www/rubik.pdf for the Rubik's cube). 
I would like to know whether there are possible applications (and if so, which ones? Existing examples would be welcome) of sheaf theory, sheaf gluing and the like to the construction of entertainment games (be mechanical, be computerized, whatever)

Thanks in advance

Comment: you are asking if topology can be funny ?

Comment: I am asking if there are games based on sheaves, or whether some of them may be easily conceivable

Comment: No comments? What a pity :(